# The corresponding activity is not being initated even after changing android manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

**  as you can see this is my android manifest xml.. there are 2 activities .. MainActivity and MainActivity2.. and according to the below code(please point me if i am wrong) i am supposed to get my class MainActivity 2 get started first.. but instead its starting MainActivty first.. please find the mistake here..**
`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.namet.myapplication.MainActivity2" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to make your activity catogorie as a launcher ,Try as follows

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: still starting the MainActivity only :(

Comment: give complete  package name   android:name="com.example.MainActivity2"